# Auto run VLC on Raspberry

Tags: raspbian, vlc, raspberry-pi4

I've installed a headless install of Raspberry PI OS lite and VLC. I'm able to start a stream with the following command:

```
vlc rtsp://192.168.1.8:7447/xo878sAewsO
```

Now I'm trying to start this script whenever the Pi is booted up. I've created an rc.local file by using `sudo nano /etc/rs.local` and placed the above code in it. However it isn't working. Also tried `vlc -vvv input_stream --sout '#rtp{dst=192.168.1.8:7447,port=7447,sdp=rtsp://192.168.1.8:7447/xo878sAewsO}'` but without succes. Should be the right command according to the documentation of [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/#RTSP_live_streaming). I'm I using the right commands? Does the rs.local file works different then a 'normal' command line?